# Tag Synonym Request: [steam-store] → [steam]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [steam-store](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-store) should be made a synonym of [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam).

We don't need to split hairs for the service - the store is just a part of the continuing transactions with the service regarding any game.

Comment: On the other hand, question like "[Running steam games on Windows from my Mac OSX drive](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32122/running-steam-games-on-windows-from-my-mac-osx-drive)" could need a [tag:steamworks] tag, since they aren't really related to Steam the "social and digital distribution platform", but Steamworks the DRM ...

Answer (score 1):

This was done a while ago*:

[image: Synonym created: Steam Store now points to Steam]

<sub>* I thought it might be worth having the update on record</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I see a difference between [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) and [steam-store](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-store).

[steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) is about the whole system, questions tagged with it indicate that the game is executed from this platform (which is, most likely, most of the time not relevant).

[steam-store](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-store) is about the store itself. Questions tagged with it are most likely off-topic, because they do not involve gaming in any way, but a shop system.